# Ignore If-Range header in nginx HTTP cache

Tags: nginx

How can I make nginx ignore the `If-Range` header when reading from a cache? My current configuration is:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header If-Range "";
    proxy_cache download;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 30m;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_pass http://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com;
}
```

I have a legacy client (in hardware, so not changeable) which includes an invalid `If-Range` header, in a request like

```
curl -k -H 'if-range: 1234' -H 'Range: bytes=195609-' https://myserver.example/...
```

My configuration works great if the cache is empty; the client gets an HTTP 206 response with the desired range. But when nginx fulfills the request from its own cache, it returns the entire file with HTTP 200, instead of just the desired range.

So how do I make nginx send a HTTP 206 response even if the `If-Range` header does not match? Can I for example rewrite the request and strike/replace the offending request header, or configure the cache to ignore the `If-Range` request header?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and I was able to make nginx completely ignore `If-Range` using this in my `location` section:

`rewrite_by_lua_block { ngx.req.clear_header('If-Range') }`

This obviously requires lua support in your nginx, which I happened to already have.